# squid + tproxy is not working properly when using url_rewriter and local apache script for youtube caching

Tags: squid

I'm using squid transparent proxy for caching and I have also youtube caching done with url_rewrite and apache script running on same machine as squid.

It was all working fine, until I decided to go with TPROXY, as it has many benefits. When I implemented the tproxy rules in iptables, everything continued to work except the playing of youtube videos - where the url_rewriter and the apache script come into play.  The url_rewriter redirects the youtube requests to a local .php script working on the Apache (on same machine)

I think it has something to do with how squid communicates with the local apache process (where the software for youtube caching works) and somehow the tproxy is screwing this up, because after implementing the tproxy the requests to the Apache are sent with the USER-IP (previous without tproxy, it was with SQUID-IP) and the reply from the apache script probably goes directly the user, instead of returning back through the squid process.

Also the apache script should be able to freely communicate with the real youtube servers, to fetch the video from there.

Here are my rules for tproxy, but I think they are pretty standart:

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT 
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1 
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT 
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 8081 


echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100 
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

The system is UBUNTU 12.04 with squid version 3.1.19.

Anyone experienced same problem and eventually some workaround with the Squid options or with iptables rules?